# Exception of type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException was thrown

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to write a simple program to get familiar with Azure. I get the above exception on the CreateTableIfNotExist(..) line. Please help.
Here is the code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var client = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        var success = client.CreateTableIfNotExist("Messages");

        var svc = client.GetDataServiceContext();


        //"Messages" is the name of the table
        return View(svc.CreateQuery<Message>("Messages").AsTableServiceQuery());
    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TaskImplHelper.ExecuteImpl[T](Func`2 impl)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(String tableName)
>      at MvcWebRole1.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\tests\AzureDemo\MvcWebRole1\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 18
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

Also, I see in the web page, it says 'resource not found'. Not sure what resource it is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally went past the error today. Hope the info below helps the rest of you. Not sure what I was doing wrong before but I simply made sure:

1. I left it alone for a few days ;)
2. The app is run with VisualStudio 2010 in **ADMIN** mode.
3. The Azure project (the one with the blue globe) is set as startup object. Hence hit F5 to run the whole app.
4. Your Compute Emulator and Storage Emulator are started (check the sys tray on the bottom right of your screen).

I am quite sure I had all this covered when I got the error before but I can't always trust myself.

Hope this helps.

And thanks to Steve Marx for the [nice demo code](http://cdn.blog.smarx.com/files/DoodleJoy_source.zip) and [pdc video](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/58d670be-bd26-4ee3-9db1-5f2767eba4f8). Has really helped me learn stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using development storage?  If so I would highly recommend that you read [Differences Between Development Storage and Windows Azure Storage Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd320275.aspx).

It sounds like you are hitting the issue that is unique to development storage in which you cannot query a table that has never contained any entities:

> In development storage, querying on a property that does not exist in the table returns an error. Such a query does not return an error in the cloud.

A dev storage workaround is documented [here](http://deeperdesign.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/azure-table-storage-what-a-pain-in-the-ass/):

> [E]nsure that the table storage knows about the structure of your objects.

```
var query = from x in context.CreateQuery(VehicleTableName) select x;
var l = query.ToList();
var v = new Vehicle();
context.AddVehicle(v);
context.SaveChanges();
context.DeleteObject(v);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes, he's using development storage (see the code).  But the exception is on CreateTableIfNotExist, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Yes I am using development storage. And thanks SMarx for your comment above. In fact I was using your video to write up that code. When I got stuck with that error, I downloaded your source code from your blog for better luck. Guess what ? Same error message when on the line: tables.CreateTableIfNotExist("Doodles"); So what is causing the problem ? Could the fact that I did a "dsInit /forceCreate" a good hour before I ran the code be part of it ? Are they even related ?

Comment: I really don't have a guess, or I would have ventured one. :)  Yes, dsinit is related to development storage, and I suppose it's possible something's broken that way.  It's too bad, because I was going to suggest dsinit /forcecreate might be a solution...

Comment: stuck with the same problem to, any solution?